# How to properly execute an async method within a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to execute an asynchronous method within a for-loop construct and then display the result. I believe the problem is that the for-loop increments before the `cryto.randomBytes` method calls the callback. How would I properly execute this for-loop ?

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var nimble = require('nimble');

var codes = [];

nimble.series([
function(callback){

     for(var i = 0; i < 100;i++){

         crypto.randomBytes(64, function(ex, buf) {
             if (ex) throw ex;
             codes[i] = buf.toString('hex');
         });

     }

    callback();

}, 
function(callback){

     for(var i = 0; i < codes.length;i++){
        console.log("Ticket " + i + ":" + codes[i]);
     }

     callback();

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right that the loop completes before the callbacks are called. You can use an anonymous function to create a scope where each iteration gets its own copy of the variable.

Also, you would call the callback after the last value has been added to the result, not after the loop:

```
function(callback){

  var cnt = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 100;i++){
    (function(i){
      crypto.randomBytes(64, function(ex, buf) {
          if (ex) throw ex;
          codes[i] = buf.toString('hex');
          if (++cnt == 100) {
            callback();
          }
      });
    })(i);
  }

}
```

Comment: A lot of unnecessary closures are being created here.

Comment: @mscdex: This could perhaps be simplified as in this special case the values are random, so it shouldn't matter which order they end up in the array. Unless different numbers take different time to produce, so that it actually introduces predictability to the random numbers, in which case it would greatly reduce the strength of the random generator.

Comment: What does any of the latter have to do with creating closures?

Comment: @mscdex: The closure is used to preserve the value of `i` for each iteration. Your solution that doesn't use a closure for that can't put the result in the corresponding item in the array, so the results ends up in the array in the order that they are completed, not in the order that the calls were made.

Comment: Right, I understand that and for this situation the order doesn't matter. I was referring to the part of your comment about random byte predictability.

Comment: @mscdex: That has to do with whether the order actually does matter or not. If you don't return the results in the order of the calls, you basically return them sorted on execution time. This may introduce a degree of predictability to the numbers, which could be crucial if the strength of the random numbers is important (considering that the `crypto` module is used).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
function(callback){

     for(var i = 0; i < 100;i++){

         crypto.randomBytes(64, function(ex, buf) {
             if (ex) throw ex;
             codes[i] = buf.toString('hex');
         });

     }

    callback();

},
```

You might try something like:

```
function(callback){

     for(var i = 0, len = 100; i < len; i++){

         crypto.randomBytes(64, function(ex, buf) {
             if (ex) throw ex;
             codes.push(buf.toString('hex'));
             if (codes.length === len)
              callback();
         });

     }

},
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an IIFE with recursivity, should work :

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var nimble = require('nimble');

var codes = [];

nimble.series([

function (callback) {

    // Using an IIFE
    (function recursive(index) {

        if (index < 100) { // i < 100
            crypto.randomBytes(64, function (ex, buf) {
                if (ex) throw ex;
                codes[index] = buf.toString('hex');
                recursive(index + 1);
            });
        } else callback();

    })(0); // i = 0

},

function (callback) {

    for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        console.log("Ticket " + i + ":" + codes[i]);
    }

    callback();

}]);
```